# Keeping menu open on a:hover

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

I was looking up well made dropdown nav bars on YouTube and  finally found a decent looking professional one. it had the Focus command to where when you click on it it opens up the dropdown menu. I decided it would be more professional to use hover instead of focus, but here is the problem when I hover over the link it opens the menu like it should but as I scroll down to click on something in the dropdown menu the dropdown menu disappears due to the fact that I am no longer hovering over the main link. I tried looking up solution online and could find none. I must put big emphasis on the fact I am trying to do this using only CSS no JavaScript. Any help would be appreciated.

```
  .nav-main{ 
   width:100%;
    background-color:#222;
    height:70px;
    color:#fff;
    }
    .nav-main .logo{
    float:left;
    height:40px;
    padding:15px 30px;
    font-size:1.4em;
    line-height:40px;
   }
   .nav-main > ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    }
    .nav-main > ul > li{
    float:left;
    }
    .nav-item{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px 20px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    }

   .nav-content{
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    background-color:#222;
    max-height:0;
    }
    .nav-content a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
    .nav-content a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .nav-sub{
    padding:20px;
    }
    .nav-sub ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    }
    .nav-sub ul li a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 0;
    }
    .nav-item:hover{
    background-color:#222;
    }
    .nav-item:hover ~ .nav-content{
    max-height:400px;
   -webkit-transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;
   -moz-transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;
    transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;

    }
```

The Html

```
<body>
<nav class="nav-main">
<div class="logo">Thomas</div>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="#" class="nav-item">Porfolio</a>
<div class="nav-content">
<div class="nav-sub">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Site 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Site 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Site 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="nav-item">CSS</a>

<div class="nav-content">
<div class="nav-sub">
Some Text
</div>
</div>

</li>
<li>
<a href="#" class="nav-item">CodeCourse</a>
</li>

</ul>
<nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yea I was just getting ready to post it. should I put the codes in  a separate comment or as a part of an edit of the main question?

Comment: Please edit the question, don't post a separate comment.

Comment: Sorry to bother you ima a noob. should I post all the css or only the css which directly relates to the dropdown menu

Comment: Anything that is related to the problem :) So if the problem is caused only by dropdown, please post its CSS.

Comment: Please include also the html. You can take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're attaching the :hover to the wrong element in HTML. You need to put the :hover in the `<li>` that contains the whole navigation, for each menu. Just add a new class to that element and change the CSS like this fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/fapfz1ms/

New HTML:

```
<body>
<nav class="nav-main">
<div class="logo">Thomas</div>
<ul>
<li class="nav-item-container">
<a href="#" class="nav-item">Porfolio</a>
<div class="nav-content">
<div class="nav-sub">
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Site 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Site 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Site 3</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
</li>
<li class="nav-item-container">
<a href="#" class="nav-item">CSS</a>

<div class="nav-content">
<div class="nav-sub">
Some Text
</div>
</div>

</li>
<li class="nav-item-container">
<a href="#" class="nav-item">CodeCourse</a>
</li>

</ul>
<nav>
</body>
</html>
```

And the CSS should look like this now:

```
 .nav-main{ 
   width:100%;
    background-color:#222;
    height:70px;
    color:#fff;
    }
    .nav-main .logo{
    float:left;
    height:40px;
    padding:15px 30px;
    font-size:1.4em;
    line-height:40px;
   }
   .nav-main > ul{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    }
    .nav-main > ul > li{
    float:left;
    }
    .nav-item{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:15px 20px;
    height:40px;
    line-height:40px;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    }

   .nav-content{
    position:absolute;
    top:70px;
    overflow:hidden; 
    background-color:#222;
    max-height:0;
    }
    .nav-content a{
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    }
    .nav-content a:hover{
    text-decoration:underline;
    }
    .nav-sub{
    padding:20px;
    }
    .nav-sub ul{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    }
    .nav-sub ul li a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px 0;
    }
    .nav-item:hover{
    background-color:#222;
    }
.nav-item-container:hover .nav-content {
  max-height:400px;
  -webkit-transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;
  -moz-transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;
  transition:max-height 400ms ease-in;      
    }
```

Comment: This works like a charm to anybody looking at this thread in the future  Inacio Schweller's suggestion worked quite well with no setbacks.

Comment: Cool! I'm glad that I helped! Would you mind upvote my answer also? Thanks!

Comment: sorry I don't have the 15 rep. I have 14 so I cant upvote

Answer (score 0):

just add this :

```
.nav-content:hover{
   max-height:400px;
}
```

see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/xgn6n8u8/)

Comment: This solution not gonna work for different heights. You are working on the assumption that will always have 400px of height, if he changes the height in the future he'd need to change in two different places.

Comment: I just used his example and provided fast solution... actually his html is not perfect and other answer address that...